# Sound with path in local notifications not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, notifications

I am downloading sound files from web, and the path I am getting is here `/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/9A3E2F61-AD0F-42B1-9BDA-81922E630AB6/Library/NoCloud/My_App/SoundTunes/My_Tune.wav`

Now I am trying every effort to set `my_tune` for notification but every time it rings `default tune` despite I have duration of `my_tune` less than `25 seconds`

Help me how can I set the path of `my_tune` to the ring for my local notifications

```
NSURL *urlTuneTime = [[NSFileManager.defaultManager URLsForDirectory:NSLibraryDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject];
NSURL *urlTuneTimeok = [urlTuneTime URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"NoCloud/My_App/SoundTunes/"];
NSURL *urlTuneTimeokk = [urlTuneTimeok URLByAppendingPathComponent:getTuneTime];
NSLog(@"here is the overall got path of time tune%@", urlTuneTimeokk);

content.sound = [UNNotificationSound soundNamed: @"../SoundTunes/My_Tune.wav" ];

//content.sound = [UNNotificationSound soundNamed: @"NoCloud/MyApp/SoundTunes/My_Tune.wav" ];
```

Answer (score 0):

As per `UNNotificationSound` documentation on [soundNamed initializer](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unnotificationsound/1649031-soundnamed?language=objc):

> This file must be located in the current executable’s main bundle or in the Library/Sounds directory of the current app container directory.

So you must save the downloaded file to `Library/Sounds` directory of your app using URL:

```
// save your file here
NSURL *soundsDirectoryUrl = [[[NSFileManager.defaultManager URLsForDirectory:NSLibraryDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] firstObject] URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"Sounds"];
NSURL *fileUrl = [soundsDirectoryUrl URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"fileName.wav"];

// create UNNotificationSound
content.sound = [UNNotificationSound soundNamed: "fileName.wav" ];
```

Comment: how can I replace `sounds` with? in my case? is it name of ring tune or folder last?

Comment: See updated answer. It seems `UNNotificationSound` initializer requires just the file name, not full path, but the file must exist either in the bundle, or in `Library/Sounds` directory

Comment: `fileUrl` is ensued warning??

Comment: It still rings default tune dear? what should I do?

Comment: I tried content.sound = [UNNotificationSound soundNamed: fileUrl.absoluteString ]; but still it rings default tune any solutions??